# Checkbox status with onEditCell event in dhtmlxGrid

Tags: angularjs, dhtmlx

I am using custom grid with checkbox. where i am getting some data from DB, example: Item1, Item2, Item3...

there are some condition.

**condition one:**
In grid, Item1 will be disable and user can only select Item3. he must not be able to click on Item2.

**Second condition:** user can select any item.

In both case i have to get selected Item and need to store somewhere.

I searched and found that we can do this kind of operation by "**onEditCell** event. but i am not sure how to use that. as by this event i am getting only stage 1 & 2 .

```
grid.attachEvent("onEditCell", function(stage,rId,cInd,nValue,oValue) {
                console.log("stage " + stage);
                console.log("rId " + rId);
                console.log("cInd " + cInd);
                console.log("nValue " + nValue);
                return true;
        });
```

How can i get the selected item.. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. used oncheck event with onEditCell..

Answer (score 0):

You may get the selected item using the getSelectedRowId() method:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_getselectedrowid.html